# Convert MISR data (NetCDF) to georeferenced TIFF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I am attempting to convert the MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_*.nc dataset with 4.4 km resolution to GeoTIFF using Python, but the tif generated is not georeferenced (see image below).  I don't have much experience with that so is there a way to do that?

```
fname = "MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P206_O112235_F13_0023.nc"
f = nc.Dataset(fname)
var = f['/4.4_KM_PRODUCTS/Aerosol_Optical_Depth']

# Read data.
data = var[:]
lat = f['/4.4_KM_PRODUCTS/Latitude'][:]
lon = f['/4.4_KM_PRODUCTS/Longitude'][:]

fillvalue = var.getncattr('_FillValue')
data[data == fillvalue] = np.nan
data = np.ma.masked_array(data, np.isnan(data))

t = rio.transform.from_origin(lon.min(), lat.max(), 0.044, 0.044)

fout="MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P206_O112235_F13_0023.tif"
ndt=rio.open(fout, 'w',
  driver='GTiff', 
  height=data.shape[0],
  width=data.shape[1],
  count=1,
  dtype=str(data.dtype),
  crs='EPSG:4326',
  transform=t)
ndt.write(data,1)
ndt.close()
```

[image: Figure georeferenced correctly]
[image: Result of Figure GEOtiff not georeferenced]

Comment: Have you seen this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329141 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it may be easier for you to use the GDAL tools that already exist to do this. You can always call them with python if you have a lot of them you need to extract.

Check out this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/163993/57277

You can take a look at the GDAL documentation here: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/netcdf.html